# How do I connect to a sql database through sql developer?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

So, I have a .sql file that I have downloaded and was wondering how I connect to it via sql developer which I have also downloaded. Do I need to create a connection with hostname and port etc? can I just connect to a file manually/directly or something?

Also, can anyone recommend a good database to practice/learn on for a beginner? Should I just download oracle 11g and play around with that?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a .sql file other than a file that has text that may or may not have valid SQL statements within?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect to a .sql file because it is not a database.  Oracle runs as a server in its own right.  If you do not already have access to a server then you will need to get one.

Fortunately, Oracle publishes a server you can use free of charge that will help get you into the swing of things.  Have a look at [Oracle Lite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-lite/downloads/index.html)

I think you might find it quite a challenge getting yourself set up with a development environment but if you are patient and determined you can get there.  Once you have a server to play with you can start to experiment with Sql, which is the language you use to interrogate the database.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! I had been learning from a site that had a table and an sql interpreter that I could type commands into, but I was wanting to practice in a 'real' environment and got stuck when I was asked to create a new connection. My only experience before was with C++ where I can just write code into the ide and compile/run it. That clears things up nicely! Thanks for the link. I'm half way through downloading 11g database; will I not be able to connect to it?

Comment: There was a second part to your question that did not really get addressed; a recommendation for a good database to get some practice.  In my view Oracle is a good starting point.  There are alternatives of course - some would recommend MySql because it is free and easy to start with but it has some non-standard behaviours which are best learned after you have a good grounding in the basics.  There is also PostgreSql which is free and a very 'pure' RDBMS, but I would stick with Oracle because it is more likely to give you commercially useful experience for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the SID as well as the ip address and port number (typically 1521) that tns listener is listening on.

Once you've connected, you'll be able to run your sql file against that database.

And yes, it would be a good idea to have a good understanding of Oracle before wandering off blindly into the world of database access (.sql files, for example)

Comment: I think this is harsh and not really helpful for a beginner.

Comment: I don't think Kevin was terribly harsh with his answer at all.

Comment: From the poster's question I would guess he is unlikely to know the terms 'SID', 'tns' or 'listener'.  That bit was, I think, unhelpful.  'Wandering of blindly' was, in my opinion, a completely unnecessary dig at someone who is only trying to advance their knowledge and does not fall into the description 'mentoring'.  @Kevin : Bad Show !

Comment: From my point of view, not understanding words like SID, tns and listener will be clues to a professional that they need to get more help.  (teach a man to fish, blah, blah, blah)

Comment: Its ok; I can look up terms. I was just a little confused about what I was connecting to etc. I am used to just opening an ide and writing code :S Thanks!